# Why can't we make functions explicit?

Tags: c++, keyword

Why can't we use the **explicit** keyword on functions? I can't think of 1 good reason not to allow this (and several to the contrary).

Why is this?

Comment: Because you can't call functions implicitly anyway? (Edit - well of course one-argument constructors and conversion operators are functions anyway, but you know what I mean. "Normal" functions)

Comment: Can you explain what you would expect to happen if you declared an arbitrary function as `explicit`? `explicit` prevents implicit conversions, how does that apply here?

Comment: @nijansen I'd expect this ( http://ideone.com/mtbfsE ) to not compile

Comment: I'm confused. Why wouldn't that compile? What's wrong with it?

Comment: And... for what reason?

Comment: I'd consider that call pretty explicit!

Comment: sorry about that, I'm a bit tired. I meant this: http://ideone.com/oPvJj1

Comment: @user1233963 You **explicitly** call `f` (because it isn't even possible to call free functions non explicitly). I think you are vastly misinterpreting the keyword.

Comment: @user1233963, That has more to do with standard conversions than with functions, really. It's sort of the same thing as `double d = 2.3; int i = d;`

Comment: @user1233963 http://ideone.com/Az0wSV

Comment: If you want to make sure `f(int)` isn't called with a `double`, then declare `extern f(double);` - which shouldn't result in any code, but when you link, if you actually use it, will fail.

Comment: @MatsPetersson meh, formaly a ODR violation. See my previous comment.

Comment: @jrok I had no idea delete worked with non-constructors/destructors. I guess that's good enough

Comment: @jrok: Surely it's not against the rules if you don't call a function that you are declaring, and you never intend to use it - although the `delete` trick is neater, of course.

Comment: @MatsPetersson You're right, it isn't. For some reason I thought standard said that every function shall have "exactly one" definiton when it realy says "no more than one". It is a violation if overload resolution selects an undefined function, though.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: An ODR violation isn't necessarily a diagnosable error, so formally you can't rely on it to cause a link failure. (Practically you can, but you're relying on formally undefined behaviour).

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I can understand why having TWO definitions for a function would potentially lead to undiagnosable problems, but (in C++) having an extern declaration of a non-existing function that is then used should lead to an error. I'm glad I don't work with compilers that produce code when the external function doesn't exist - since I sometimes make mistakes of the type `int func_xyz()` in a headerfile, and then "implement" `int funcXyz` in the source file (because I'm obviously not really a competent programmer). That would be hard to identify if the compiler calls some random location.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Indeed; as I said, you can practically rely on a diagnosis. Apologies if my observation of formally undefined behaviour was excessively pedantic.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Sure, just trying understand where this would apply at all [aside from really crap implementations of a compiler/toolchain].

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you want to achieve (forbid type conversions for your function arguments) can be achieved easily by declaring a deleted template version of the function:

```
template <class T> void f(T) = delete;

void f(int){}

int main()
{
    double k = 4;
    f(k); //error: use of deleted function ‘void f(T) [with T = double]’
}
```

Comment: Without C++11 you can make `f` a template and only implement the specialization you want.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier which works only for one argument because you cannot partially specialize functions before C++11 ;)

Comment: @BenjaminBannier you can *overload* the template and just not define it at all - however you will get linker errors instead of the more direct "deleted function" error.

Comment: @nijansen: In that case just do a tag dispatch with a `operator()` taking a parameter pack to forward to the `f` ... wait :(

Answer (score -1):

`explicit` is used to indicate that a function can't be used to perform an implicit type conversion. Since type conversions can only be done using constructors and conversion operators (like `operator int()`), `explicit` only makes sense when applied to these.

Historical note: before 2011, it couldn't be applied to conversion operators; this was widely regarded as a shortcoming, which has now been fixed.